# Initialize array structure in headerfile shared by cpp files of two different applications

Tags: c++

I am in a situation wherein i need to develop two applications both related which share certain common information .

So declaring an array structure and initializing it with predefine values in header 
file is the right approach?

any better way of doing this other than using some common config file?

Comment: You can use shared memory for all that common information. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html

Comment: @ The Apache -Information is static and it doesnt have to be shared at run time.Also these apps run on two different system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a singleton class with the array you need as a member.